# How can I Change Chart Labels in Google Data Studio?

Tags: looker-studio

[image]

I have a chart that is using multiple data sources and I want to change the labels to reflect the dates of those data sources instead of all just saying "Record Count".

Comment: It would be easier for users to visualise the issue and and test out suggestions on a live Report as field names are specific... If you could replicate the scenario on a fresh Google Data Studio Report using sample data that would also be proof that it is a reproducible issue! if you could then share that Google Data Studio Report publicly and add a link in the question, it would allow fellow users to test it out. Without a Reproducible Example it would be **difficult to pinpoint a suggestion and the issue, e.g. Data Set, Data Source, Report, Fields, Chart Configuration, Temporary Outage**...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using blend data the column names can and should be renamed at this point.
First click on the "AUT" symbol left of the field then enter the new column name.

[image]

It is also possible to edit column of a grafic by change the names under "Metrics".